# Cannot read property 'teacherId' of undefined when calling the array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var teacherArray=[];
```

I have created an array variable.
I am creating an array with the key and value. and pushing these data to the teacherArray.

```
   random={
    teacherId:TeacherId,
    day:day,
    periodCount:period,
    class:Studentclass,
    section:Studentsection,
    startTime:schoolStartTime,
    endTime:schoolEndTime 
};
teacherArray.push(random);
console.log(teacherArray);
```

In the console I am able to see the created array. But when the submit button clicked i am calling the array like

```
teacherLength=teacherArray.length;
    for (let k=0;k<=teacherLength;k++)
    {   
        var teachId=teacherArray[k].teacherId;
        console.log(teachId);
    }
```

In the console displays the teacherId, but next line shows the error as

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'teacherId' of undefined
>   [image]

Comment: you have off by 1 error, add <

Comment: Someone marked this question to close  as a typo. I strongly believe that, missing an operator is not typo in programming.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I strongly agree. This kind of error is a *logic* error, even if the solution involves changing only one character.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero index based. So when you write `k<=teacherLength` you are requesting more than what array have. That should be changed to

```
k<teacherLength
```

Comment: @suresh thank u bro:)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are 0 indexed. You are having,

```
for (let k=0;k<=teacherLength;k++)
```

Make it,

```
for (let k=0;k<teacherLength;k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is reading an ***extra item***, you need to replace

```
for (let k=0;k<=teacherLength;k++)
```

with

```
for (let k=0;k<teacherLength;k++) //notice < instead of <=
```